# complexity and big oh notation on algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I need som help understanding how this works! how do I go about calculating the complexity of 'Computing the first half of an array of *n* items' or 'displaying the third element in a linked list' ? I need someone to explain how this works, theses are just examples, so be free to use your own if it helps explaining! thank you.

Comment: You can try thinking about number of iterations at first, then move onto Big O and theta notations. Suppose you want to find the maximum element from an given array of n element, to do so you will need n iterations. So the complexity in this case is O(n). Again, suppose you need the third element of an array, you can just access it by arr[ 3 ] (here "arr" is an array name and I'm assuming you are familiar with accessing particular array elements this way). This operation requires 1 iteration, so it has O(1) complexity. Applying bubble sort to an array requires n^2 iterations, thus O(n^2).

Comment: possibly helpful: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at how the processing time of the algorithm grows as the size of the input grows. I'll take your two concrete examples:

> Computing the first half of an array of *n* items

We need to process *n/2* items. If *n* doubles, then the processing time should also double. Consequently, this is a linear operation (i.e. O(n)).

> displaying the third element in a linked list

We *always* want to display the third element, so the size of the list doesn't actually matter. If it doubles, we don't care; the processing time is not affected. Consequently, this is a constant-time operation (i.e. O(1)), it doesn't depend on the size of the input.